# How can I design 'base things' which could apply all apps in django?

Tags: django

What I want to do is to create main page(`main.html`) where I can direct to each app and want to make `base.html` which gonna be base template of all apps by extending it. What I tried to do is like below ;

```
my_project
├── app1
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── app2
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── my_project
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── main.css
├── main.html
├── base.html
├── manage.py
└── views.py
```

But I'm not sure if this structure is right. Give me advice, please.

Comment: You better check these tutorials first: [Writing your first Django app, part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/), [Writing your first Django app, part 6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial06/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better place your templates in templates directory of the root location as well as corresponding applications , then specify in your templates section of your settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
```

also set

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', )
STATIC_URL = 'http://yourdomain.com/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = './media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (     
     ./static_files,
)


STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

So the resulting structure is

yourproject+
           |
           +main.py
           |
           +templates+
           |         |
           +         +base.html (this is checked last)
           |
           +static_files+
           |            |
           |            +css
           |            |
           |            +js
           |     
           +media+
           |     |
           |     +images
           |
           +yourproject+
           |           |
           |           +urls.py
           |           |
           |           +wsgi.py
           |           |
           |           +settings.py         
           |
           +yourapp+admin.py
                   |
                   +models.py
                   |
                   +views.py
                   |
                   +tests.py
                   |
                   +templates+
                             |
                             +base.html (this is checked first)
```

This way Django will check all the templates directories within your apps, and after that the root locations's templates will be used if no child templates found in apps to fetch base.html and any inheriting templates. Placing html templates in a separate directory will help you to keep design clean and separate from source code and configuration files.

Comment: Do I need to make `base.css`, too? I want to unite base design of all apps including main.html.

Comment: Any of your css files should be in your static_files/css so when you run ./manage.py collectstatic they will be taken into static - which is the destination directory. All static files, including css and javascript files, should resize in a dedicated location as configured - see the tree.